# Stopping AngularJS from not executing HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I am wondering how to compute HTML in an AngularJS object (Like this: `{{names}}`) but I have an `'<a>'` element inside the object.

It comes out like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">link text</a>
```

I want this: [link text](http://www.example.com)
I want the links in [this page](http://sixty.netne.net/temporary/stackExample.html) to be the ones.

Comment: But I wanted that link to work.

Comment: am I not understanding your question correctly? i'll take the easy route first, <a href="whatever">{{names}}</a> ?

Comment: @Sixtysixpointsixty-four No, you want us to read _the code you expect to generate._

Comment: When is say <a href="http://www.example.com">link text</a> I mean the output was that.

Answer (score 3):

Im pretty sure the answer you are looking for can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) `ng-href` will allow you to use the `{{}}` syntax to dynamically generate a url from your angular controller.

Comment: No I need it to generate a link.

Comment: Sorry I guess I don't understand what you are asking then, can you please clarify what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Ok I added a link to a page containing my progress.

Comment: Right under the example link under my example code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this `<div ng-bind-html="name"></div>`.

Note: you may need to do an '$sce.trustAsHtml()' if your HTML contents contain links. But be sure that what content goes in the HTML is safe before doing this. See more details [Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)